# Creating an Array from a Column of a Text File in Python

Tags: python, arrays, decimal

I am attempting to read in a text file  called Obit 1 and create three different arrays called time(N), lat(N), long(N), containing the time, latitude and longitude where N is the number of rows in the file. This way I can find the longitude, latitude, and time in decimal hours at any point in the text file with length N. In this particular file N has a value of 1112, but I want it to be a generic N so I can use this code for other text files as well. This is the first few lines of the text file:

```
Year    Month   Day Hour    Minute  Second  Millisecond Longitude   Latitude    Altitude
2019    3   17  5   55  55  0   108.8730074 50.22483151 412.6226898
2019    3   17  5   56  0   0   108.9895097 50.53642185 412.7368197
2019    3   17  5   56  5   0   109.1078294 50.8478274  412.850563
2019    3   17  5   56  10  0   109.2280101 51.15904424 412.9640113
2019    3   17  5   56  15  0   109.3500969 51.47006828 413.0772319
2019    3   17  5   56  20  0   109.4741362 51.78089533 413.1901358
2019    3   17  5   56  25  0   109.6001758 52.09152105 413.3025291
2019    3   17  5   56  30  0   109.728265  52.40194099 413.414457
2019    3   17  5   56  35  0   109.8584548 52.71215052 413.5259984
2019    3   17  5   56  40  0   109.9907976 53.02214489 413.6371791
2019    3   17  5   56  45  0   110.1253475 53.33191916 413.7481083
2019    3   17  5   56  50  0   110.2621604 53.64146827 413.859132
2019    3   17  5   56  55  0   110.401294  53.95078695 413.970057
```

This is the code I used to read in the text file and it is working well when I print the row (I commented it out for now because I was just using it to check if it was working properly).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
file_name = 'C:\\Users\\Saman\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Beginning Text Files\\Orbit 1.txt'

data = []
with open(file_name) as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        row = line.split()
        row = [float(x) for x in row]
        data.append(row)
        #print(row)
```

So now I'm trying to create the three arrays that I want as stated above, but I'm getting stuck. This is what I have now for latitude, but I'm getting the error 'index 1112 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1112.' I am relatively new to Python so I would appreciate any and all help!

```
columns = ['Year','Month','Day','Hour', 'Minute', 'Second', 'Millisecond', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Altitude']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)

N = len(df)

lat = np.zeros(N)
for i,e in df.iterrows():
    lat[N] = e['Latitude']
```

Also, I know doing the longitude long will be the same as the latitude/lat above, but I'm confused as to how I would use the data in the text file to convert the time to decimal hours and then create the time array.

Comment: Please give a sample of the output you expect.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel do you mean the output that contains the error or the output of when I print the row? Or do you mean the output I am wishing to achieve?

Comment: No. I mean the output without errors. i.e you intended result.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel I would like to be able to find the value of latitude, longitude, and time in decimal hours at any point in the 1112 lines of data. So for instance if I wanted to know the latitude at the first line of data I would simply enter ``` lat[0] ``` and the output would be 50.22483151

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list `data` that stores the list of all row values, you can map all elements(i.e rows) of data to a function that extracts the particular item using the column number as the item index. Here:

```
mytime = list(map(lambda x: x[3], data)) #list of time i.e column 3

longtd = list(map(lambda x: x[7], data)) #list of longitude i.e column 7

lat = list(map(lambda x: x[8], data)) #list of latitude i.e column 8
print(lat,'\n\n', longtd, '\n\n', mytime)
```

> It works perfectly for me, see the result:

```
[50.22483151, 50.53642185, 50.8478274, 51.15904424, 
51.47006828, 51.78089533, 52.09152105, 52.40194099, 
52.71215052, 53.02214489, 53.33191916, 53.64146827, 
53.95078695]

[108.8730074, 108.9895097, 109.1078294, 109.2280101, 109.3500969, 
109.4741362, 109.6001758, 109.728265, 109.8584548, 109.9907976, 110.1253475, 
110.2621604, 110.401294]

[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 
5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: When I tried to use that I got an error 'list index out of range' and I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: It works perfectly, i've updated my answer to reflect to result

Comment: Besides, is point 1112 the last row of you data? You should remember Python works with zero(index), so to get values at point 1112 you should use you index as 1111(i.e lat[1111]. longtd[1111], and  mytime[1111]

Comment: When I put in the code you provided and try to run it, I get the error list index out of range. I think it's because my data isn't in the correct format maybe? I tried to `print(data)` to see what it looks like and this is it. Do you think this is what the issue is?

Comment: `[[2019.0, 3.0, 17.0, 5.0, 55.0, 55.0, 0.0, 108.8730074, 50.22483151, 412.6226898], [2019.0, 3.0, 17.0, 5.0, 56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 108.9895097, 50.53642185, 412.7368197], [2019.0, 3.0, 17.0, 5.0, 56.0, 5.0, 0.0, 109.1078294, 50.8478274, 412.850563], [2019.0, 3.0, 17.0, 5.0, 56.0, 10.0, 0.0, 109.2280101, 51.15904424, 412.9640113], [2019.0, 3.0, 17.0, 5.0, 56.0, 15.0, 0.0, 109.3500969, 51.47006828, 413.0772319], [2019.0, 3.0, 17.0, 5.0, 56.0, 20.0, 0.0, 109.4741362, 51.78089533, 413.1901358],`

Comment: There's 1112 rows including the header in the text file. If you have a better way of opening the file and reading it I'd be open to trying that. I am still new to Python and just trying things out.

Comment: Try this: print(lat[1111])

Comment: I tried that. I'm getting an error with the original code you provided. This is the error.

Comment: `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-122673f0849e> in <module>
     16 df = pd.DataFrame(data,dtype=float,columns=columns)
     17 
---> 18 mytime = list(map(lambda x: x[3], data)) #list of time i.e column 3
     19 longtd = list(map(lambda x: x[7], data)) #list of longitude i.e column 7
     20 lat = list(map(lambda x: x[8], data)) #list of latitude i.e column 8 IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Please provide a link to your text file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219555/discussion-between-sjcarlso-and-seyi-daniel).